# List PowerBI workspace collection keys from arm template

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

When using ARM templates to deploy various Azure components you can use some functions. One of them is called [listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#listkeys) and you can use it to return through the output the keys that were created during the deployment, for example when deploying a storage account.

Is there a way to get the keys when deploying a Power BI workspace collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you mentioned  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#listkeys), if we want to use listKeys function, then we need to know resourceName and ApiVersion.

From the [Azure PowerBI workspace collection get access keys API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/powerbiembedded/workspacecollections#WorkspaceCollections_getAccessKeys), we could get resource name 
`Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections/{workspaceCollectionName}` and API version `"2016-01-29"`

So please have a try to use the follow coding, it works for me correctly.

```
"outputs": {
    "exampleOutput": {
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections', parameters('workspaceCollections_tompowerBItest')), '2016-01-29')]",
      "type": "object"
    }
```

[image]

Check the created PowerBI Service from Azure portal

[image]

Whole ARM template I used:

```
{

  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "workspaceCollections_tompowerBItest": {
      "defaultValue": "tomjustforbitest",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},

  "resources": [

    {

      "type": "Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections",

      "sku": {

        "name": "S1",

        "tier": "Standard"

      },
      "tags": {},

      "name": "[parameters('workspaceCollections_tompowerBItest')]",

      "apiVersion": "2016-01-29",

      "location": "South Central US"

    }

  ],

  "outputs": {
    "exampleOutput": {
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections', parameters('workspaceCollections_tompowerBItest')), '2016-01-29')]",
      "type": "object"
    }
  }


}
```